# Fay: how to show a value and use this string in JS?

Tags: javascript, haskell, fay

I'm mixing old JS and new Fay-generated JS, and I'm trying to get a string representation of some data from Fay. I defined

```
jshow :: Bool -> String
jshow d = show d
```

It's not just a `Bool` in the real code, but the type doesn't change the error.

This is compiled with

```
fay Linguatron.hs --strict Linguatron
```

And then I call it in JS with

```
Strict.Linguatron.jshow(trainingData);
```

when `trainingData` is the result from another Fay function which I call from JS.

This gives an error that `xs` is undefined, and this is inside the Fay standard code! It's on line 436, which looks like

```
// Make a list.
function Fay$$list(xs){
  var out = null;
  for(var i=xs.length-1; i>=0;i--)   //<<-- This line
    out = new Fay$$Cons(xs[i],out);
  return out;
}
```

The full trace is

```
Fay$$list               @   linguatron.js:436
Fay$$jsToFay_string     @   linguatron.js:281
(anonymous function)    @   linguatron.js:822
Fay$$$.force            @   linguatron.js:52
Fay$$_                  @   linguatron.js:29
(anonymous function)    @   linguatron.js:173
(anonymous function)    @   main.js:56
m.event.dispatch        @   jquery.js:4670
r.handle                @   jquery.js:4338
```

I'm using Fey 0.23.1.12 and it happens on Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.

Comment: "when trainingData is the result from another Fay function which I call from JS." - it seems like this would be relevant information here - how exactly are you producing this value? Obviously the argument passed to `Fay$$list` is actually just `undefined` - so what produced that bogus value?

Comment: It's not undefined, though... the value of `trainingData` at the time of the error is `function ($p2){return new Fay$$$(function(){var x = $p2;var xs = $p1;return Fay$$_(Fay$$_(Fay$$cons)(x))(xs);});}` @user2407038

Comment: @S_FLUID This is very useful information (should be in the question!) - seems like `trainingData` is a function while you expect it to be a list. Again, how you produced this value is the source of your problem.